# Standard way to convert errors into warnings?

Tags: python, exception, warnings

I've got this snippet of code, which converts certain `Exception`s into nonfatal `RuntimeWarning`s:

```py
    ...
    for f in filter(_tty_check, [sys.stderr, sys.stdout, sys.stdin]):
      cur_encoding = _tty_get_encoding(f)
      if f.encoding != cur_encoding:
        try:
          f.reconfigure(encoding=cur_encoding)  # 1. CATCH THE ERROR
        except (io.UnsupportedOperation, LookupError) as err:
          war = RuntimeWarning(*err.args)  # 2. CONVERT IT INTO A WARNING
          war.with_traceback(err.__traceback__)  # 3. RESTORE TRACEBACK
          if cur_encoding.startswith('x-ebcdic'):
            try: f.reconfigure(encoding='cp037')
            except (io.UnsupportedOperation, LookupError): pass
          warnings.warn(war)
    ...
```

However, this business of `try...except`, then creating the Warning, then manually sticking junk onto it looks a bit awkward and verbose.

Is there anything like the **opposite** of warnings.filter? Instead of a block where specified warnings become errors, I want a block where specified *errors* become *warnings*.

Or is there any way to just "cast" an error to become a warning without this kludgy 2-step where I inject the traceback back in?

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion, you can define a function to convert exceptions into warnings, as example you can attempt a division by zero inside a try-except block, or any other expectation, It converts the exception to a warning, prints it, and continues with the remaining code, setting a default value for the result in my case you can change the behavior to fit in your case.

```
import warnings


def convert_error_to_warning(exception):
    warning = RuntimeWarning(*exception.args)
    warning.with_traceback(exception.__traceback__)
    return warning


try:
    # Some code that may raise an exception
    result = 1 / 0
except Exception as err:
    warning = convert_error_to_warning(err)
    # print(err)  # 1
    print(warning)  # 2
    # warnings.warn(warning) #3

    # Continue with the rest of the code
    result = None  # Set a default value or handle the situation as needed

# Continue with the rest of the code
print("Code continues executing after the error.")
print("Result:", result)
```